# How to replace substring of dictionary values using Re

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to loop through a dictionary and replace a substring using Re, but my dictionary just ends up with empty values. I've outlined my code below:

```
mydict = {
    'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': 
    [
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/',
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.set.com/',
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.one.com/'
    ],
    'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': 
    [
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/'
    ]
}

val = "├─BROKEN─"

for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
  for i, s in enumerate(v):
      v[i] = re.sub(r'.*├─BROKEN─', '', val)
```

This code results in an dictionary without values:

```
mydict = {
    'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': 
    [
        '',
        '',
        ''
    ],
    'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': 
    [
        ''
    ]
}
```

What I want is:

```
mydict = {
    'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': 
    [
        'http://www.broken.com/',
        'http://www.set.com/',
        'http://www.one.com/'
    ],
    'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': 
    [
        'http://www.broken.com/'
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Change this `v[i] = re.sub(r'.*├─BROKEN─', '', val)` to `v[i] = re.sub(r'.*├─BROKEN─', '', s)`

Comment: You replace `val` which is exactly the string to replace. That's probably a typo and you meant to use `s` instead of `val`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex here, seems a little expensive. Use string `replace()` and `strip()`:

```
mydict = {
    'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': 
    [
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/',
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.set.com/',
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.one.com/'
    ],
    'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': 
    [
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/'
    ]
}

val = "├─BROKEN─"

for k, v in mydict.items():
    mydict[k] = [x.replace(val, '').strip() for x in v]

print(mydict)

# {'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': ['http://www.broken.com/', 'http://www.set.com/', 'http://www.one.com/'],
#  'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': ['http://www.broken.com/']}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code with modified regexp.

```
import re

mydict = {
    'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': 
    [
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/',
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.set.com/',
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.one.com/'
    ],
    'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': 
    [
        '├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/'
    ]
}


for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
  for i, s in enumerate(v):
      v[i] = re.sub(r'\├─BROKEN─', '', s)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': [' http://www.broken.com/'],
 'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': [' http://www.broken.com/',
                                              ' http://www.set.com/',
                                              ' http://www.one.com/']}
```

As was stated into the comment `|` is a [special character](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand re better! +1